# What I have to write in the string "table" of combiTable1D parameters when data are stored in a txtFile?

Tags: modelica

I have created a txt.File named combitable1.txt in

```
C:\Users\Yamaha R6\Desktop\FileOpenModelica
```

I want to "load" data of this file into combitable1D in OpenModelica. If you see the image, under the voice "table", I have wrote :

```
loadResource("C:/Users/Yamaha R6/Desktop/FileOpenModelica/combitable1.txt")
```

but when I simulate the model following error occurs :

[image]

> 15:51:20 Translation Error
>       Class loadResource not found in scope (looking  for a function or record)

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use loadResource function in this case. You can leave the table name as it is

```
parameter Real table[:, :] = fill(0.0, 0, 2)
  "Table matrix (grid = first column; e.g., table=[0,2])"
```

Your file formattig should be like following, assuming a text file myFile.txt:

```
#1
double myTable(200000,2)
0.000000 0.110519
0.001000 0.316248
0.002000 0.505827
0.003000 0.703204
0.004000 0.894942
0.005000 1.072796
...      ...
```

With following inputs to the Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable

```
parameter String fileName = "C:\\SomeLocation\\myFile.txt";
parameter String tableName = "myTable";
```

Answer (score 2):

The fields do not have the right values.

table: leave empty

tableName: "tab1" (might be able to skip quotes)

filename: use loadResource - but give the full Modelica name:
ModelicaServices.ExternalReferences.loadResource("c:/users....");

(Technically loadResource is more for the case ModelicaServices.ExternalReferences.loadResource("modelica://A/combiTable.txt"); )